# How to make session data available to all templates in Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, npm, express-session

I want access `user_name` data after login to HTML templates. Since I am using `sess.user_name` in `app.post('/login', (req, res)` which render to *home_main.html*. Hence, after redirecting to different HTML pages from *home_main.html* `user_name` is not accessible. How to make this available in all templates?

**index.js**

```
// Import all function modules
...
// Define Express app settings
...
app.set('views', __dirname + '/template/demo');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/template')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/template/demo')); 

const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'Educhain app', 
    cookie: {maxAge: 60 * 1000 * 30}
}));
var sess;

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
        login.execute(req.body.username)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Logged in successfully');
                    sess=req.session;
                    sess.user_name= req.body.username;
                    
                    console.log(req.session.user_name);
    
                    const result = {
                        status: 'success',
                        message: 'Logged in successfully',
                        username: sess.user_name
                    };
                    
                    res.render( __dirname + "/template/demo/" + "home_main.html", {result:result}); 
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    const result = {
                        status: 'error',
                        message: 'Login failed. Enter valid credentials',
                        error: e
                    };
                    console.log(e);
                    res.render( __dirname + "/template/demo/" + "login.html", {result:result});
                });
    });
```

This `sess.user_name` data is only available in *home_main.html*. As I have sent it in `res.render("home_main.html", {result:result});` . It is in result object. But how do I make this user_name available to further HTML views?

For example, on *home_main.html* there are 2 buttons - **Register for exam** and **View Transactions**, which open a HTML forms. After clicking on any of these buttons, `sess.user_name` is not available on HTML templates. Please advise.

Comment: Are you doing this sess=req.session; in each of your route before accessing?

Comment: Nope! Just accessing `sess.user_name` in every module of index.js, as it is global. And it's working in those modules. But it is not accessible in the rest templates.

Comment: Are you not passing the object like {result:result} in the other views?

Comment: Yes! That is why I think this `{result: result}` is accessible only in file which is referred to in `res.render()`. 
Like in the above case, session data is available `"home_main.html"`. But on `home_main.html` there are 2 buttons - **Register for exam** and **View Transactions**, which open HTML forms. It is not available in those forms.

Comment: If they are rendered by node.js you can send result object there too right?

Comment: `result` is available to immediate rendered HTML template only. How can access in next redirects?
`home_main.html`-->Click **Register for exam**-->Opens `RegisterExamForm`. ==> here result is not accessible.

Comment: If these are separate HTML pages, then you should can send your data as query params. If these are alsoejs pages, then better to have a wrapper around your ejs view which will render either home_main or other views( registerexamform etc.). One more option with ejs pages could be to send req back to server and render a different view, this way you can use {result:result} here too. In any case, you should add a little of your front end code to show how you are **actually** showing these pages. That way someone can help you better.